# Loop through dataframe and execute SQL query

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which has 6 rows with SQL queries  in each line. I want to execute every query and assign the output to a dataframe. currently I have 6 line of codes as below:

`df6 <- tbl(conn,sql(df[6,]))`
Is there a way I can loop through and assign the same in one statement using dplyr mutate function?
I tried below:

```
i <- 1:nrow(df)
df %>% mutate(paste0('df',i) <- tbl(conn,sql(df[i,])))
```

This throws the following error:

> Error: Column `q1` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a little unclear, but assuming you have a dataframe with a column titled 'sql_code', you can just apply a function to each element in that column

```
lapply(df$sql_code, function(x) tbl(conn, sql(x)))
```

you will end up with a list that you can put together with `bind_cols()` (if the data frames are of the same dimensions)

Comment: Thanks this is close to what I was looking. I have a dataframe with sql queries. I need to execute every one of them and assign the output to a new dataframe.Now how do I assign this dynamically?  It should be like paste0('df',i) = lapply(...)

Answer (score 0):

With the help from Shinobi_Atobe's function I could develop it into what I wanted as below:

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(df$sql_query,function(x) {tbl(conn, sql(x))}), paste0('df', 1:nrow(df))), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

This executes sql query from every row in the dataframe and stores the output in individual dataframes named as df1,df2...